# How do scripts like elasticsearch docker entrypoint manage vairable names with special characters

Tags: bash, sh

Elasticsearch is just an example, its container takes as environment variables stuff like `node.name` or `path.repo` . When I try to access such variables with :
`${path.repo}` all I get is `bad substitution` same for :

- `${path\.repo}`
- `"${path\.repo}"`

How are these variables even declared outside of docker?

I'd like a solution that works with any shell since I plan to use it globally.

I'm trying to overload some of these variables (easy) then verifying their value (where I'm stuck) with if blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't valid *shell* variable names, so you're not going to be able to set (or access) them in the shell. Other languages don't have that particular restriction. For example, in Python I can run:

```
>>> import os
>>> # set environment variable path.repo
>>> os.environ['path.repo'] = 'foo'
>>> # access environment variable path.repo in a child process
>>> res = os.spawnvp(os.P_WAIT, 'python', ['python', '-c', 'import os; print(os.environ["path.repo"])'])
foo
```

We can see the environment variable `path.repo` is visible in the subprocess spawned by `os.spawnvp`.

---

If you're restricted to a typical shell, your options are more constrained. You can use the `env` command to set variables like this:

```
env path.repo=foo somecommand ...
```

To access the variables in the shell, you would need to parse the output of the `env` command:

```
env | awk -F= '/path.repo/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I knew that you can do that in other languages, but I specifically need it inside the shell. So there isn't any solution to access non valid shell variable names? (vars with "." or "-")

Comment: See my update regarding the use of the `env` command.

Comment: the awk solution is the one I've used but with "export" instead of env and cut instead of awk which is still essentially the same, doesn't help with my if. I think I'll just set that to a new variable and use that instead.